# Failed to bring up network interface

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy

Having a problem with a quad port network card. Can't find the error can someone help please?

`dmesg | grep eth`

```
    [    6.064749] e1000bp: eth3: e1000_probe: Silicom PXG4BPI series adapter
    [    6.084852] udevd[361]: renamed network interface eth1 to eth3
    [    6.378488] e1000bp: eth1: e1000_probe: Silicom PXG4BPI series adapter
    [    6.704917] e1000bp: eth5: e1000_probe: Silicom PXG4BPI series adapter
    [    6.708904] udevd[354]: renamed network interface eth2 to eth5
    [    7.019834] e1000bp: eth2: e1000_probe: Silicom PXG4BPI series adapter
    [    7.048921] udevd[354]: renamed network interface eth2 to eth6
    [    7.072996] udevd[355]: renamed network interface eth1 to eth4
```

`ifconfig eth3 up`

```
    eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:e0:ed:07:d2:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`dmesg` shows:

```
    [  269.985904] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth3: link is not ready
```

`ethtool -i eth3`

```
    driver: e1000bp
    version: 8.0.35.silc.5.56.4-NAPI
    firmware-version: N/A
    bus-info: 0000:02:04.0
    supports-statistics: yes
    supports-test: yes
    supports-eeprom-access: yes
    supports-register-dump: yes
    supports-priv-flags: no
```

`ethtool -e eth3`

```
    Offset          Values
    ------          ------
    0x0000:         00 e0 ed 07 d2 0e 30 04 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0010:         14 c4 03 21 03 46 2c 00 74 13 2c 00 74 13 e8 34
    0x0020:         08 40 2c 00 00 00 02 21 c8 18 ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0030:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0040:         08 c3 63 ff 04 50 02 21 c8 08 ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0050:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 02 06
    0x0060:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0070:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 78 7c
    0x0080:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0090:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00a0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00b0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00c0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00d0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00e0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x00f0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0100:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0110:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0120:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0130:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0140:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0150:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0160:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0170:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0180:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x0190:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01a0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01b0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01c0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01d0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01e0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    0x01f0:         ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

`lspci -vvv`

```
    02:06.1 Ethernet controller: Silicom Ltd. Silicom Quad port Copper Giga Ethernet 546GB Bypass Server Adapter (PXG4BPI) (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Silicom Ltd. Silicom Quad port Copper Giga Ethernet 546GB Bypass Server Adapter (PXG4BPI)
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (63750ns min), Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 9
    Region 0: Memory at fe4a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 4: I/O ports at a400 [size=64]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [e4] PCI-X non-bridge device
            Command: DPERE- ERO+ RBC=512 OST=1
            Status: Dev=02:06.1 64bit+ 133MHz+ SCD- USC- DC=simple DMMRBC=2048 DMOST=1 DMCRS=16 RSCEM- 266MHz- 533MHz-
    Capabilities: [f0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
            Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: e1000bp
```

`lsmod | grep e1000`

```
    e1000bp               172714  0
```

`uname -a`

```
    Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Tested the cable. It works fine on another NIC.

Comment: With all the udev renaming going on, is it possible eth3 isn't currently referring to the physical port you think it should be?  If you do `ifconfig eth3` does it have the MAC address you expect? And does it show packets being received?

Comment: It does have the mac expected. Here is the output of: ifconfig eth3
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:ed:07:d2:0e
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: Hmm, 0 rx packets.  Even without an IP configured and with a known good cable you should be getting a few random broadcasts (arps, etc.).  With all due respect, are you *certain* the cable is plugged into the right port?

Comment: Yes am sure it is plugged to the right port well all the 4 ports are plugged. I tested the cables on another network card on the same machine it works fine. I have a doubt on the network card itself. Either the driver is wrong or the card is defective. the probability of defective card is little as i guess it would not have detected the card itself. As for the driver i am unable to debug. i don't know what to search for as i can't see any error.

Comment: Only other suggestion I can make then is to notice the bus ids reported by ethtool (02:04.0)  doesn't match lspci (02:06.1).  Multiple adapters in the same machine?  Maybe needs some special driver handling?  And it is very possible the transceivers on the card are shot - that wouldn't affect the kernel seeing the card itself (but I hate pointing fingers at hardware)